# Convert a colormap image into data values according to a legend

Tags: plotting, matrix, image, data-acquisition

I have this image

[image: colormaped image]

that I want to turn into data using this gradient

[image: gradient]

black being 0, white being 1, and all the colors in between accordingly, so I could later use `ListPlot3D` to make a height map.

I tried using `ImageData`, to work something out using RGB values of each color point, but in the end the purple was higher than the blue, so that didn't workout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import data, take only one column from the legend, and extract `ImageData` from the legend:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JxTr.png"];
leg = ImageTake[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRqiH.png"], All, {1, 1}];
legdata = ImageData[leg, DataReversed -> True][[All, 1, 1 ;; 3]];
```

Connect the RGB values to a number in $[0,1]$:

```
rules = Rule @@@ Transpose[{legdata, Subdivide[Length@legdata - 1]}];
```

Extract `ImageData` info from the image:

```
imgpoints = ImageData[img][[All, All, 1 ;; 3]];
```

Employ `Nearest` to find the best approximation of the color in `img` using colors available from `leg`:

```
pts = Table[
    Nearest[legdata, imgpoints[[i, j]]][[1]], {i, 1, 
     Length@imgpoints}, {j, 1, Length@imgpoints[[i]]}] /. rules;
```

Draw points:

```
ListPlot3D[pts, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]